# What determines whether the 'Compatibility View' button appears in Internet Explorer 8 or not?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, ie-developer-tools

On some sites I'm developing, I noticed that the 'Compatibility View' button is shown beside the address bar. Yet when I view other websites, this button is not always available to me.

What determines whether or not this button is shown to the user?  Does it have to do with the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">` header tag?

(Screenshot below of what I'm talking about)

---

[alt text http://img380.imageshack.us/img380/4858/compatabilitybutton.png](http://img380.imageshack.us/img380/4858/compatabilitybutton.png)

Comment: I think the DOCTYPE declaration has something to do with it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the only thing that affects this is indeed the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">` tag.

Note from the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28VS.85%29.aspx) on document compatibility: This tag must appear in the `<head>` section of your code before *any other tags* except the **`<title>`** tag.

Comment: [This][1] is another useful SO question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897409/ie8-compatibility-view-button-is-enabled-even-when-ieemulateie7

Comment: Beyond the META tag, you can also specify this via the HTTP header. Or the site may appear on the CompatView list.