# Internet Explorer 8 Compatibility button

Tags: internet-explorer-8

When I open http://www.google.com in IE8 the compatibility button to switch between IE7/8 mode does not display. Why?

Answer (score 1):

See answers to this question :

[IE8 Compatibility View Button is enabled even when IE=EmulateIE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897409/ie8-compatibility-view-button-is-enabled-even-when-ie-emulateie7)

and its related links.

The Compatibility button should not display when this META tag is set :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

Google does have the tag set in its home page.